# NullPointerException when getting image from drawable folder and resize it

Tags: java, android, image, drawable

I was having some problem when trying to get the image from drawable file and resize it and plot onto the map. Here is the code:

```
final Drawable d = EventDrawableImage.resizeCurrentLocImage("current_loc",
            context);
    for (int iii = 0; iii < pathGeometries.size(); iii++) {
        final int counter = iii ;
            EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                private long time = 0;
                public void run()
                {
                    time += 1000;
                    EventDetail.handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                    moveNext(pathGeometries.get(counter).getX(),
                            pathGeometries.get(counter).getY(), 0, d);
                }
            }, 1000); 
    }
```

And in my moveNext() method, I am plotting the marker onto the map:

```
public static void moveNext(double coordx, double coordy, int k, Drawable d){
    // Set center
    Point p = new Point(coordx, coordy);
    EventMain.mMapView.zoomToResolution(p, 1);

    // Add marker
    PictureMarkerSymbol graphicIcon;
    graphicIcon = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);
    Symbol symbol = graphicIcon;
    HashMap<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    attrMap.put("currentLoc", "User Current location");

    EventMain.graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(p, symbol, attrMap));     
}
```

And my resizeCurrentLoc() method:

```
public static Drawable resizeCurrentLocImage(String locPic, Context context) {
    String uri = "@drawable/" + locPic;
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
            context.getPackageName());
    Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) res).getBitmap();
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 40, 40, true));
    return d;
}
```

I am able to use the returned drawable and plot it onto the map by other functions but not this. I suspect it was because of the handler thingy. The error message as the stack trace:

```
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at Extra.EventDrawableImage.resizeCurrentLocImage(EventDrawableImage.java:37)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at Controller.EventController.getDirection(EventController.java:308)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at AsyncTask.GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.java:36)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at AsyncTask.GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.java:1)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime(5886):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-17 19:44:27.568: E/AndroidRuntime
```

Any ideas because it was working for other functions but not this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line is EventDrawableImage.java:37

Comment: That line is the int imageResource that line. Nope, context is not null because it was working for other function also

Comment: what does *fot the other function also* mean ?

Comment: Sorry for my English, as in my other features was using that resize method as well and it was working fine

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
            context.getPackageName());
```

[getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method takes :

**.** Resource name as first parameter

**.** Resource directory name like raw,drawable,.. as second parameter

**.** Application package name as third parameter

So, get resource id using name as:

```
 int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(locPic, "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
```

and also make sure `context` is not `null`.

Comment: it does not explain a NPE, though

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
        context.getPackageName());
```

returns null, which can't be stored in an int (it could be in an Integer) and therefore causes the NPE.

But a return value of null is probably an indication of something going wrong - see that other answer.